# Is there a perfomance penalty when I use multiple projects as an alternative to multiple directories in one project with C#

Tags: c#

I previously had 5 projects and each had 5-10 directories in my C# application. Now I have changed this to 10 projects can each has 2-3 directories.

In my web application I now reference these ten projects instead of before when it was more like 2-3.

Is there any performance penalty if I continue my development in this way and if I add more projects as the application gets bigger. The things I am wondering about are the one off load time, the memory usage (is every DLL that I reference stored in a project itself) and the time when my code has to move from objects in one project to another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you reference all these projects, there is just a slight penalty for the jitter to load the assemblies.

But I think you are asking the wrong question. You should not divide your code into different assemblies based on how many classes or directories you have. If so, one project would be optimal.

You should concern yourself with what could be made internal. If you have those ten assemblies, what parts of your program can be hidden from the rest of your program. Is there perhaps a tree of dependencies where some of your projects does not have to reference others?

That should be your call, not how many files of text goes where.

Answer (score 1):

Performance difference would be negligible(startup time may be several milliseconds slower). If your application architecture is better with multiple projects, then go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not noticably at runtime.

Visual Studio will be slower to load multiple projects. With 5-10 projects, you probably won't notice, but with 30-40, you will start to notice.

Compilation will (in general) be slower. This is because project dependencies need to be copied to the output folder of the project that depends on them. If you have more projects, you have more output files to copy around. You can mitigate this by setting the output folder for each project to the same place, but this is more difficult with a web application project, and it's a pain anyway.

At runtime, there will be a performance penalty involved in all those extra disk accesses when resolving the assemblies.

However, there will be negligible (if any) performance impact when actually executing your code. It's no more expensive to call code in one assembly than in another (once it's loaded and JITed, and assuming that it wouldn't have been inlined).